# Detect ajax request no connection status and state

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I'm working with pure JavaScript (No jQuery and no others...) and I'm writing some code to make an AJAX request. I noticed that when the internet connection fails, on chrome, firefox and ie those are the values in `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange:`

```
xmlhttp.readyState=4
xmlhttp.status=0
```

Since I would like to handle network connection problems is this a good way to do it?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==0){//No internet connection

        //code to handle network error
    }
}
```

This code seems to work for me, but I haven't seen any documentation abuot this, nowhere! Do you think is this a solid solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [online/offline events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");

  function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

    status.className = condition;
    status.innerHTML = condition.toUpperCase();

    log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "Event: " + event.type + "; Status: " + condition);
  }

  window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
});
```

```css
#status {
  position : fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font : bold 1em sans-serif;
  color: #FFF:
  padding : 0.5em
}

#log {
  padding: 2.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  font: 1em sans-serif;
}

.online {
  background: green;
}

.offline {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
<p>This is a test</p>
```